# svnkit: how to get working copy revision number?

Tags: java, svnkit

I am using SVNKit 1.3.2 and trying to obtain working copy revision number.

Working copy is checkouted also with SVNKit, but when I'm trying to call

```
clientManager.getLookClient().doGetYoungestRevision(destination);
```

I got FileNotFoundException telling me that 'format' file is not found under destination path, ex `/path/to/working/copy/format`

I can see 2 troubles: 
- It tries to access 'format' file right in working directory root, while this file supposed to be in .svn folder

- There is not file in this .svn folder.

Any clues? Thank you!

Comment: I am having the same problem as you. This is very strange. I've tried your answer, but it's not quite what I need.

Answer (score 5):

Seems to be it should be done through SVNStatusClient:

```
clientManager.getStatusClient().doStatus(destination, false).getRevision().getNumber();
```

Though still don't understand what's the problem with doGetYoungestRevision(destination)...

Comment: After committing changes in a working copy, I needed to use `.doStatus(wc, true).getRemoteRevision()` to obtain the revision of the commit. `.doStatus(wc, false).getRevision()` just gave me the revision that was initially checked out. There are probably some subtleties here I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because `doGetYoungestRevision` is for a repository, not for a working copy.

I was hoping to achieve the same things as you, and found out that when `destination` is pointing to a repository, it returns the last revision number of the repository.

The class in itself is for working with repository, you can look at the documentation [here](http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/admin/SVNLookClient.html).